# icon font not working in firefox

Tags: html, .htaccess, css, font-face, access-control

I'm trying to use icon font, so far it works good in all browsers besides firefox, I don't understand why, instead of icon it just shows value that is in `data-icon` attribute
Can anyone explain why it is not working in firefox (latest)?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icon-font';
  src: url('//bit.ly/ZxomPz') format('woff'),
       url('//bit.ly/WPGMJF') format('truetype'),
       url('//bit.ly/16eqBwn') format('eot'),
       url('//bit.ly/16eqLDZ') format('svg');
}

[data-icon]::before {
font-family: 'icon-font';
font-weight: 400 !important;
content: attr(data-icon);
text-transform: none;
margin-right: 3px;
position: relative;
top: 8px;
right: 5px;
font-size: 31px;
line-height: 0;
}
```

```
<span data-icon="1" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Comment: Unable to link to your fonts :: Error (403)
It seems you don't belong here! You should probably sign in. Check out our Help Center and forums for help, or head back to home.

Comment: No SVG font format ??

Comment: @MilchePatern added .svg font file, still doesn't work. as for the 403 error, it's because fonts are located in my drop box account, and in order to see them you need to be logged in as me. But everything is fine with files, it's gotta be something to do with my font face markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a @font-face declaration has recommended. Maybe you can try re-writing yours with this example.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lobster13Regular';
    src: url('/skins/default/media/fonts/lobster/Lobster_1.3-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/skins/default/media/fonts/lobster/Lobster_1.3-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/skins/default/media/fonts/lobster/Lobster_1.3-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/skins/default/media/fonts/lobster/Lobster_1.3-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/skins/default/media/fonts/lobster/Lobster_1.3-webfont.svg#Lobster13Regular') format('svg');
}
```

Also, make your your server is delivering the correct 'Mime-type' (ttf|otf|eot|woff) and permits accessibility for outside ressources (Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*")

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but here's a solution that worked for me and I don't see it in the answers (except the short mention by @Milky ways patterns).

Create an `.htaccess` file with the following information and save it in the same folder your fonts are located:

```
<FilesMatch ".(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

More information here:

- Firefox is because Firefox doesn't allow cross-domain fonts: http://red-team-design.com/firefox-doesnt-allow-cross-domain-fonts-by-default/
- http://alittlecode.com/font-awesome-icons-not-working-in-firefox-probable-cause-and-a-fix/